# Como controlar o posicionamento de uma div com position fixed?

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Como eu posso fazer para que quando a minha div da direita chegar na div da área de comentários voltar a ficar fixa? Quando ela chega em um número X de distancia do topo eu aplico um position fixed para ela ir acompanhando o conteúdo: 
[Link da materia](http://cissamagazine.com.br/blog/modelos-high-end-com-scanner-iris)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 630) {
                        $('.paginas-especiais-post').css({
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: '60px'
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('.paginas-especiais-post').css({
                            position: 'relative',
                            top: '0'
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

[image: Print da situação que quero resolver]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achei uma alternativa para seu problema que foi adicionar mais uma restrição no if:

```
&& $(this).scrollTop() < $('.comentarios-pag').position().top - 630
```

se o scroll for maior que `641` e menor que a distância da div comentários subtraindo o tamanho (mais alguns espaços Ex. navbar e paddings).

Abs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var especiais = $('.paginas-especiais-post');

        if( $(this).scrollTop() > 641 && $(this).scrollTop() < $('.comentarios-pag').position().top - 630 ) {
          especiais.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '60px'
          });
        } else {
          especiais.css({
            position: 'relative',
            top: '0'
          });
        };
    });
});
```